# Connect to RDS from EC2 instance in a different Availability Zone (AZ)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

OK, so I have a VPC with three app servers and an instance of Postgres in RDS.

I have a security group called 'rds-staging' that allows inbound connections on port 5432 from a security group called 'app-elb-staging'.

'app-elb-staging' is the security group applied to all of my EC2 instances, and it allows outgoing traffic to go anywhere.

The RDS instance is in AZ us-east-1e. I can connect to it from my EC2 instance in us-east-1e (10.0.3.*), but not from any EC2 instances in us-east-1a (10.0.1.*) or us-east-1c (10.0.2.*):

```
deploy@ip-10-0-3-220:~$ nc -zv xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
Connection to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432 port [tcp/postgresql] succeeded!

deploy@ip-10-0-1-155:~$ nc -zv xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
nc: connect to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 (tcp) failed: No route to host

deploy@ip-10-0-2-90:~$ nc -zv xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
nc: connect to xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

Has anyone seen this before? I've checked the DNS, and each machine is resolving the hostname to the same IP (10.0.3.x).

Comment: *"each machine is resolving the hostname to the same IP"* ... Is it a 10.x.x.x IP? Or a public IP?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the DB hostname resolves to a 10.0.3.x IP

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the DB instance is not publicly accessible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally figured the root cause of this issue. The AMI I was using was creating a bridge that caused the connection issue due to it colliding with the IPs of my subnets. The output from `sudo route -n` looked like this on an affected instance:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-92:~$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
```

Any connection to 10.0.2.* would then fail:

```
deploy@ip-10-0-1-92:~$ nc -zv 10.0.2.53 22
nc: connect to 10.0.2.53 port 22 (tcp) failed: No route to host
```

Removing the bridge with `sudo ifconfig lxcbr0 down` resolved the issue, but using an AMI that does not set this bridge up in the first place corrected the root.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this kind of problem caused by one of two reasons:

1. The route-tables attached to the various subnets are configured wrong.
2. There is a Network ACL in play (unusual).

You don't need to define routes for each subnet, they're implicit in the table. Double-checking the IP addresses that your DNS entry resolves to on the other-AZ instances will ensure that it is in the VPC.

Network ACLs can come into play, but you have to set them up. By default, they're wide open. This is why I tagged it as unlikely, but it can cause problems like this. That said, the 'no route to host' error is suggestive that this isn't your problem.

Comment: Have had a look at my route tables, but they seem fine from what I can gather. Each subnet is attached to the same route table, which has two routes: `10.0.0.0/16 - local` and `0.0.0.0/0 - routed to the nat instance`. The network ACLs also seem fine - wide open, as you mention.